# How possible rebooting from Linux to Windows makes sound from headphones vanish?

Tags: windows-7, linux, laptop, audio

I have Windows 7 Home Premium 64bit, dual booting with Linux Mint. The laptop is Asus X54C.

The problem: Every time I reboot from Linux to Windows (Restart the computer while on Linux, and when GRUB shows up select Windows), I have no sound in my headphones until I switch the laptop off. The built-in laptop speakers work fine; but I hear nothing from my headphones.

Switching the laptop off and then on again will not invoke the issue. Rebooting the laptop from Windows to Windows will not invoke the issue either.
Installing sound drivers from Asus website or uninstalling them and sticking with basic drivers Windows installs itself won’t solve the issue.
On Linux Mint, I always have sound from my headphones whether I reboot or not.

```
Audio:     Card Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Family High Definition Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k3.19.0-32-generic
```

Comment: How strange... don't hear about Windows not resetting hardware very often. Could probably unplug & re-insert the headphones?

Comment: @Xen2050 Tried it many times, sadly not working.

Comment: Hmmm... how about in the System / Device Manager, try to disable and then enable the device?

Comment: @Xen2050 Nope, no luck either.

Comment: You're not taking the headphones out of your ears, are you? That's my last idea ;-)

Comment: @Xen2050 Sorry, I have them firmly stuck in my ears right now ;P